# Entire hard drive disappears randomly on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-management

I have an MSI laptop (GL75 9SE) with an NVMe SSD disk (Partition C) and an additional 1 TB hard drive (Partition D).

I have Windows 10 Pro 22H2 Build 19045.2251 with the last updates
In the last few weeks I have noticed that my second hard drive keep disappearing randomly once a several days and sometimes twice a day!

When it disappeared I wasn't doing anything specific, mostly web browsing with Firefox.

The system doesn't crash or anything since it is installed on the NVMe but I can't access my files on the D partition.

It's not only the D Partition that disappears but the entire disk is no longer listed in disk management tool.

Restarting my laptop makes everything goes back to normal.

Here's SMART HDD report on the disk

What can I do?

```
Manufacturer - Seagate
Model - ST1000LM049-2GH172
Serial number - (hidden)
Firmware - SDM1
Firmware upgrade - supported
Capacity - 931.5 GB
Form-factor - 2.5"
Interface - SATA
SATA version - 3.1
ATA version - ACS-3
Advanced Format - supported
Logical disks - D:

Performance:
   Maximum speed interface - 600 MB/s
   Current speed interface - 150 MB/s
   Buffered read speed - 188 MB/s
   Average read speed - 165 MB/s
   Stable read speed - 172 MB/s
   Instability of reading - 4%
   Average access time - 17.71 msec
   Rotation rate - 7200 rpm
   Volatile write cache - supported, enabled
   Read look-ahead - supported, enabled
   Automatic acoustic management - not supported
   Advanced power management - supported, enabled, current value - 128
   Command queuing (NCQ) - supported

Reliability:
   Count of sensors - 23
   Fast self-test - supported, duration in minutes - 1
   Full self-test - supported, duration in minutes - 124
   Maximum temperature limit - 60 °C
   Maximum recommended temperature - 55 °C
   Current temperature - 36 °C
   Highest temperature - 58 °C
   Remapped sectors - 0
   Connections to the power - 3816
   Hours worked off - ?
   Free-fall control - not supported
   SCT Command Transport - supported
   State - nonfaulty
   Start of analysis - 20-Nov-22

Security:
   Drive access restriction - supported, disabled
   Enhanced security erase - supported
   Instant information destruction - not supported
   Time of data deletion in minutes - 124
   Hidden partition - supported
   Partition access restriction - supported, disabled
   Trusted Computing - not supported

S.M.A.R.T.
   #   Name                    Flags   Value Worst Thresh RAW(Dec)        RAW(Hex)     
   1   Raw Read Errors         POSR--  83    64    6      205811548       0C446F5C     
   3   Spin Up Time            PO----  99    99    0      0               00           
   4   Start/Stop              -O--CK  97    97    20     3875            0F23         
   5   Reallocated Sectors     PO--CK  100   100   36     0               00           
   7   Seek Errors             POSR--  88    60    45     692735404       294A4DAC     
   9   Power-On Time           -O--CK  90    90    0      152282360456394 8A80000024CA 
   10  Spin Retry              PO--C-  100   100   97     0               00           
   12  Power Cycles            -O--CK  97    97    20     3816            0EE8         
   184 End-to-End Errors       -O--CK  100   100   99     0               00           
   187 Uncorrectable Errors    -O--CK  100   100   0      0               00           
   188 Command Timeout         -O--CK  100   1     0      7625            1DC9         
   189 High Fly Writes         -O-RCK  100   100   0      0               00           
   190 Airflow Temperature     -O---K  63    42    40     656539685       27220025     
   191 G-Sense Errors          -O--CK  100   100   0      1               01           
   192 Power-Off Retracts      -O--CK  100   100   0      82              52           
   193 Load Cycles             -O--CK  1     1     0      211234          033922       
   194 Temperature             -O---K  37    58    0      60129542181     0E00000025   
   197 Current Pending Sectors -O--C-  100   100   0      0               00           
   198 Offline Uncorrectable   ----C-  100   100   0      0               00           
   199 Cable CRC Errors        -OSRCK  200   195   0      7348            1CB4         
   240 Head Flying Hours       ------  100   253   0      237387137425596 D7E7000020BC 
   241 Lifetime Writes         ------  100   253   0      46943431905     0AEE0BECE1   
   242 Lifetime Reads          ------  100   253   0      49950784676     0BA14C7CA4   

   Flags: P - prefailure warning, O - updated online, S - speed/performance
          R - error rate, C - event count, K - auto-keep

Program version - 7.4.0.9873
Operating system - Windows 10 Build 19045 x64
Host controller:
   Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
   Revision - 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The disk is failing - you have "Raw Read Errors" and "Seek Errors".

"Raw Read Errors" aka "Raw Read Error Rate" is
[described](https://media.kingston.com/support/downloads/MKP_306_SMART_attribute.pdf)
as :

> relative to the number of sectors read this power cycle.
> This attribute may include both Uncorrectable ECC (UECC) errors,
> and Uncorrectable RAISE (URAISE) errors.

You should backup all necessary data on the disk,
then replace the disk.

Comment: Thank you for your answers it confirmed what I didn't want to believe

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a computer, a lot, in the past, they are still my customer,
they have an All-in-one HP with Windows 10 (x64).
The Seagate hard drive was Always doing the exact same thing.

This is what I did:

1. Went to HP.com and searched for the computer through they're support.
2. Opened the software and drivers page.
3. Selected which software is installed.
4. Got the exact firmware needed for the hard drive.

Firmware
Seagate Hard Drive Firmware Update - HPDE/HPRD Rev.A -
96.5 MB - Jul 6, 2016

Type: Firmware

Version: HPDE/HPRD Rev.A

Operating systems: Windows 10 (64-bit)

Release date: Jul 6, 2016
File name: sp76598.exe  (96.5 MB)

Description:

This package provides a tool that will update the Seagate hard drive firmware.
This package is available for supported platforms that are running a supported operating system.

Fix and enhancements:

- Fixes an issue where certain flash commands could lead to a DNR (drive does not come ready) condition.
- Fixes an issue which causes SMART errors to occur on the hard drive during system power on.
- Fixes an issue where the drive capacity shows 0GB available
- Added graceful failover when the flash has too many P/E cycles

### Direct Download
https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp76501-77000/sp76598.exe

Make sure you check your support page(s) for driver, etc. this might/might not
work on your hard disk.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I'll try this as soon as I have time to backup my data and I'll keep you updated